# Evaluar múltiples casos de resultados condicionales

Tags: c#, if, condiciones

Estoy evaluando un **rango extenso** de resultados condicionales.

**Modificado:**

- Los resultados a evaluar son de tipo: `int` y  `string`

Comencé con el uso del **switch :**

```
switch (valor)
{
   case 1: case 2: case 3:          
       // hacer algo
       break;
   case 4: case 5: case 6: 
       // Hacer algo
       break;
   case ......
       // Hacer algo
       break;
   default:
       // Hacer algo
       break;
}
```

pero debido a que el rango de evaluación es muy extenso no se si: **¿debo continuar usando el `switch` o es preferible usar una serie de sentencias `if`?**

```
if (valor == 1 ||  valor == 2 || valor == 3)
{
  // ...
} else
if (valor == 4 || valor == 5 || valor == 6)
{
  // ... 
}
```

**Nota:** Quizás la pregunta se vea como basada en opiniones, pero necesito saber que sería más recomendable, ya sea por legibilidad del código, rendimiento o  estética.

Comment: No hay diferencia de rendimiento entre las 2 opciones. Por lo demás, realmente es una cuestión de opinión.

Comment: Ok, siendo así entonces yo debería eliminar la pregunta, ya que no aporta nada.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el rango de evaluación?

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave aproximadamente 40 resultados.

Comment: @J.Rodríguez podrías usas un `between`. en vez de `if (valor == 1 ||  valor == 2 || valor == 3)` sería `if (valor >= 1 &&  valor <= 3)`.

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave, buena observación. Solo que olvide puntualizar (pensé que no era necesario) que evaluaré tanto resultados `int` como `string`, en este caso **valor** sería de tipo string, por lo tanto con `between` se vería afectado, no?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tal vez te convendría poder expresar varias condiciones para una misma variable de forma más compacta.

Por ejemplo, en SQL puedes usar el operador `IN`:

```sql
select *
  from tbl
 where a IN (1,2,3,4,5)
```

... que es mucho más compacto que expresarlo de esta forma:

```sql
select *
  from tbl
 where a = 1 or a = 2 or a = 3 or a = 4 or a = 5
```

Aunque en C# no existe un operador similar como el `IN` en SQL, con un método de extensión + genéricos puedes crear algo que se parezca y que te sirva para distintos tipos:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace MisExtensiones
{
    public static class OperadoresEx
    {
        public static bool In<T>(this T valor, params T[] otrosValores)
            => otrosValores.Any(v => EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(valor, v));
    }
}
```

Este método de extensión te permite efectuar condiciones `OR` de forma más compacta:

```
using MisExtensiones;

// ...

int valor = ...;

if (valor.In(1,2,3))
{
    // ...
}
else if (valor.In(4,5,6))
{
    // ...
}
else
{
    // ...
}

string cadena = ...;

if (cadena.In("abc", "def", "zzz"))
{
    // ...
}
else if (cadena.In("otro","valor",null))
{
    // ...
}
else
{
    // ...
}
```

Nota: Obviamente, usar esta técnica es menos eficiente que usar los `OR` o `CASE` explícitos, aunque la diferencia en la mayoría de las situaciones será muy poca. Si el rendimiento no se ve afectado y lo que buscas es mayor legibilidad, entonces me parece una solución perfectamente aceptable cuando tienes que manejar una gran cantidad de condiciones.

Comment: Si, he usado el operador `IN` en SQL , buena respuesta, aunque tengo que aprender sobre la programación con `Linq` , mi cerebro la asimila confusa, pero poco a poco aprenderé el uso de `expresiones lambda`